# Unique identifier for HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Besides the ID, if you say you want a unique identifier for an HTML element (let’s say a div).

I browsed the DOM for something (like a number or string) that was unique for each element; but the DOM was big and I failed to find that on the Internet.

Is there a property (in the DOM obviously) that is unique only to that element? (Other than the ID and also you don't specify it, but it comes when the DOM is constructed.)

Comment: FWIW, IE offers a [uniqueID property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534704\(VS.85\).aspx) DOM objects which, when accessed, generates a unique identifier for that element.  It's not part of the spec and won't help you in other browsers though.

Comment: I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/renaatdemuynck/57b1b78b6611e6d5d866) with a shim that adds IE's uniqueID functionality to other browsers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Depending on the objective, here are two suggestions.

Unless you actually need to express the id as some kind of string, you can save the normal DOM reference.

If you do need to express it as a string for some reason, then you'll need to assign a unique id yourself.

```
var getId = (function () {
  var incrementingId = 0;
  return function(element) {
    if (!element.id) {
      element.id = "id_" + incrementingId++;
      // Possibly add a check if this ID really is unique
    }
    return element.id;
  };
}());
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, I should make you aware of it's `data` function with which you can assign any kind of information to an element: http://api.jquery.com/data/ In fact jQuery itself uses an unqiue ID to implement that, however I'm not sure if it's possible to access that ID in any reliable way.

Answer (score 8):

The only other identifier I can think of is the [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) of the element in the document.

For instance, the title link inside the heading of this very page has an XPath of

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/h1/a
```

But like [Pekka already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298500/unique-identifier-for-html-elements/3298517#3298517), it depends on what you want to do. And I don’t think you can get the XPath easily from the DOM in JavaScript, despite XPath being available nowadays in JavaScript engines.

Comment: @Andy Xpath is available in modern browsers. I just dont think there is a way to get the Xpath to a node by some sort of native function yet. At least I am not aware of any.

Comment: @AndyE I think it's about time it became a W3C recommendation, don't you think? 
It's so useful for manipulating the DOM.

Comment: @risto I think the main problem is that the DOM is rarely completely static and predictable from the root to the target element.  Any changes to the DOM render your previously-gotten xpath useless and it's safer to just rely on class names, unique IDs or using selectors relative to elements with those attributes.

Comment: @AndyE The XPath is really useful for end-to-end testing, where you know when and how the DOM should be manipulated. It would be nice not to have to rely on an IDE like Selenium

Answer (score 5):

[Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) has a property, "uniqueID", for every element. The problem is that the other browsers don't support it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a library or roll your own to create a unique identifier. [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) has [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return
> the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of
> matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same situation, and while I was looking into some DOM elements in the Chrome developer tools inspector, I noticed that they all seem to have a property like `jQuery11230892710877873282` assigned with a unique number.

Obviously the number after 'jQuery' is different every time you load the page. My guess is that jQuery is generating this internally every time it tries to access or manipulate any DOM element.

I played a little bit with it, and it looks like elements that are never accessed/manipulated by jQuery may not have this property, but the moment you do something like `$(elem)`, the property will be there. So, since we're using both [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and [Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash), I devised the following function to return a unique ID regardless of whether the element actually has a DOM id attribute.

```
_.reduce(
    $(elem), 
    function(result, value, key) { 
        if(_.startsWith(key, 'jQuery')) 
            return value;
        }, 
    0)
```

Comment: I found out that this is the jQuery `expando` attribute, more information about it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922441/what-is-the-meaning-of-jquery-random-attributes-in-html-expando-attribute

Answer (score 1):

There is the `name` attribute that can be addressed by `document.getElementByName`.

I don't think other unique identifiers exist - even though you could simulate one by setting a property (like `title`) to a unique value, and then query for that. But that is kludgy.

Comment: Looking for a solution similar to the identify function in prototype. Unfortunately, I'm using jQuery. I think I would better do by creating my own identification function.

Comment: `name` is very much **not** unique. Multiple elements can have the same name. There is no `document.getElementByName` but there is `document.getElementsByName` where Elements is **plural**.