# what is the meaning of jquery random attributes in html ? [expando attribute]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what is the meaning of these jquery random attributes in html and how jquery use them

[image]

any ideas please ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the jQuery expando attribute, it's a bit random because it's generated on page load, it's `"jQuery" + (new Date()).getTime()` (to avoid possible naming conflicts)  but you'll notice the attribute is the same for all elements.

This is they key in [`$.cache`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L7) for the element's events and data...it's stored this way for a few reasons, the main is to avoid circular references.  The ID is actually [`$.uuid`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L10) which is just an incrementing counter used for each element's key in `$.cache`.

You can get the current attribute in jQuery 1.4+ with a simple `alert($.expando)`, for an example of how it's used, say you wanted the data for that `#wmd-preview` element, doing this:

```
$("#wmd-preview").data()
```

Is doing this:

```
$.cache[$("#wmd-preview")[0][$.expando]]
```

Also note that jQuery [intentionally strips these out](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L225) when you call [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the content.