# Strange object in Angular JS - explanation?

Tags: angularjs

I was messing around in the console and came across a strange object: `ng-1392763474770`

Logging it returned:

> ReferenceError: ng is not defined

What exactly is this? I couldn't bring anything up through my searches.

P.S. This page is just for demo, there is no html.

Comment: why is this interesting?

Comment: @EliranMalka It's not interesting to someone who don't understand it

Comment: @IlanFrumer, it's not a matter of understanding the issue at hand, i'm afraid the question lacks interest to the community. for the least, an explanation on the motivation to solve it would help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This number is a date timestamp:

```
Date(1392763474770)
"Wed Feb 19 2014 01:49:41 GMT+0200 (IST)"
```

The reason why you get `ReferenceError: ng is not defined` is because it's not a valid javascript, instead you can use the object bracket notation:

```
 element['ng-1392763474770']
```

This is a `JQLite.expando` , from [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.13/src/jqLite.js#L101):

```
 jqName = JQLite.expando = 'ng-' + new Date().getTime()
```

jqLite uses it to cache element's data and avoid circular references.

See this: [what is the meaning of jquery random attributes in html ? [expando attribute]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922441/what-is-the-meaning-of-jquery-random-attributes-in-html-expando-attribute)