# jquery inserting jquery attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). It is inserting some attributes like below in the html tags.
jQuery110208269020320702063="365"

```
<SPAN class=EditNotAllowed title="Label Editing not allowed" jQuery110208269020320702063="366" jQuery11020551343224003024="366">3.3.</SPAN>
```

I have no idea about stopping these getting inserted into html tags. How i can stop these...?

Comment: how are you adding the dom/html?

Comment: why do you want to stop it? it is an harmless attribute used internally by jQuery(expando attribute)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150592/why-does-my-form-element-have-a-random-jquery-attribute & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922441/what-is-the-meaning-of-jquery-random-attributes-in-html-expando-attribute

Comment: Off Topic Comment but still i gotta ask this who's @AnoopJoshi?

Comment: What code do you use to get the  HTML? jQuery should strip these attributes out for you. Also, what version of jQuery is this?

Comment: @lonesomeday i'm using jquery-1.10.2 and the code wich i'm using is document.getElementById("Filearea").innerHTML

Comment: @ArunPJohny this is html file converted from xml and included into web page(of course that's what my application do). Once my work is done. It should be reverted to xml format. when this is converted back to xml my xml parses throwing errors because of these attributes.

Comment: `$( '#Filearea' ).html()` instead of using the basic javascript method, don't know if jQuery will strip those for you, but, you know... if you're using the library might as well use it for reading what you're adding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in the comments above that you use `document.getElementById("Filearea").innerHTML` to get the HTML out again. Don't do this.

jQuery inserts these properties to make its functionality work (data and events, principally). For compatibility in all browsers (IIRC this only affects old IE) you have to use the jQuery method rather than the native DOM method.

```
$('#Filearea').html()
```

This should work.