# There's thousands of jquery1426844443154="14" in the code i'm trying to maintain, what is it?

Tags: jquery, html

This comes from work and it is from a single html page that works like a static link collection. It has some jquery for some fancy graphics like slidetoggle. But mostly it is html and some javascript. I've never touched jquery before, so i have no idea if it comes from some kind of jquery set up. 
The page has static links that are grouped up into different groupings, so there are a lot of divs to make these grouping. 
In the html theres litteraly 1795 cases of these jqueryRandomnumber="randomnumber"
in nearly every div

```
<div class="showall" jquery172020993790578498256="1" jquery17205293602707599523="2" jquery17208396580797622919="1" jquery172047581286466724065="1" jquery17205780739718125003="1" jquery17209776296434692728="1" jquery17208889652145314046="1" jquery172003507568165644309="1" jquery172021817888861562146="2" jquery17206691773524292328="1" jquery17203812942718951728="1" jquery172003410621774544392="1" jquery17205094481124126803="1" jquery172048240188746380175="1" jquery17208414675834554786="1" jquery17206392143033692195="1" jquery17202275689624604294="2" jquery17208827235064209673="1" jquery17205964900533654569="2" jquery17208405116114532796="29" jquery172005032817254245098="1" jquery172038260194805826564="1" jquery172025707437412835926="1" jquery172004063213984691122="1" jquery172017233999640638192="1" jquery17203767404928004338="1" jquery17207101594459615917="1" jquery172004675143924620401="1" jquery172044392503366592406="1" jquery172049569135959513577="1" jquery172045430325235615887="1" jquery17209706059704440837="1" jquery17209069720655619533="1" jquery17205141876729168477="1" jquery172018236576897422862="1" jquery17208044320496860091="1" jquery17205820288657717009="1" jquery17206614058555467508="1" jquery17209987710888412922="1" jquery17206851067028617586="1" jquery17201408842988124811="1" jquery17209034923418193914="1" jquery17201476816544167739="1" jquery17202378085555806122="1" jquery17208233357235249242="1" jquery1720999075477301121="1" jquery172005096768818096298="1" jquery17206885678670706947="1" jquery1720489902072261905="1" jquery17208520196406589048="1" jquery17203841726368643937="1" jquery17208338640545842426="1" jquery17208358764909050245="1" jquery17203544618678171298="1" jquery17207387507796938024="1" jquery17204878855701234619="1" jquery172039793277546318384="2" jquery1720647451771033204="2" jquery172047149877179093363="2" jquery17209055907456081677="2" jquery172031254101155120584="2" jquery17205229647412451595="2" jquery172016620047667947907="2" jquery17206773623962910558="2">Show everything</div>
```

I can't find any mention in the javascript code that actually references jqueryRandomNumber="something" in any way, not by regex or litteral. 
If i search for "jquery" in the page the only mention in the code is these weird markups. There's not even any mention of anything remotely named jquery in any of the javascript code.

So i can't actually find that these do anything in the code, so I've deleted all the occurances and can't see that there's any problem with the page, but i am super curious what it is and what kind of purpose it could have had. Is it from some kind of library that has inserted these, and then the original author never bothered to delete them?

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922441/what-is-the-meaning-of-jquery-random-attributes-in-html-expando-attribute

Comment: Likely someone took a generated HTML file and pasted it back to the development environment. You can safely remove them there.