# Extra jQuery Object Defined -- Sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've noticed that on *some* websites that use jQuery, there's an extra jQuery object defined.  If you open your javascript console you'll be able to see it

```
> jQuery1710009775503538548946
Object {events: Object}
events: Object
handle: (a)
toJSON: ()
__proto__: Object
```

The variable name seems to correspond with the string in `jQuery.expando`.

What is this object?  I don't think it's an alias for the global `jQuery` object as the following returns false

```
jQuery == jQuery1710009775503538548946
```

Also, what triggers the presence of this variable?  It doesn't exist on all site that use jQuery, including the jQuery homepage.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922441/what-is-the-meaning-of-jquery-random-attributes-in-html-expando-attribute

Comment: @DinoMyte I'm not sure that covers it?  It mentions the expando attribute, but doesn't make any mention of why jQuery defined a new top level object based on this expando number.  (i.e. I know they use the expando number to avoid conflicts, but what is this object for?  Why does it only sometimes get instantiated?)