# crossbrowser unique identifier for a html tag

Tags: html, cross-browser, uniqueidentifier

Is there some kind of unique identifier for a HTML tag in a page?
I see in Mozilla there is the `uid`, is it cross browser? (I do not really care about IE6...)

I am also aware of [Unique identifier for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298500/unique-identifier-for-html-elements) They missed the `uid` there

Comment: You mean an automatic unique identifier, that doesn't have to be specifically assigned, correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no cross browser, future proof uid, see [allowed attributes by HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I found the attribute `uid` to work crossbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what you're looking for, here's a bit of jQuery that will take a selector and give a `data-uid` attribute to each match that resembles the asp.net ClientID.

```
$("div").each(function() {
    var uid = $.map($(".findMe").parentsUntil('body').andSelf(), function(o, i) {
        return o.id || o.tagName.toLowerCase() + $(o).prevAll(o.tagName).length;
    }).join('_');
    $(this).data("uid", uid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IE has the `uniqueID` property that will automatically generate a unique id for each element. I've also created a [shim](https://gist.github.com/renaatdemuynck/57b1b78b6611e6d5d866) for other browsers.