# Jquery: Is there anyway to identify uniqueness of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Let me explain

I have a DOM which contains element of popup windows. HTML something looks like:

```
<div class='editor'></div>
<div class='editor'></div>
```

I am working on Chrome extension that has to find all elements by class `editor`, if it does not find certain text, add it.

So far it's working. The DIV contains a `textarea`. What actually happening that if a person removes the text, it's added again. It's happening because I am using a timer to *sniff* whether new windows popped up.

Is there anyway I can figure out that a certain text was already added in a DIV? Does elements have some internal ID?

PS: While I am writing this question, a thing came across in my mind that, I go thru all elements have class `editor` and assign unique Ids as `editor1,editor2..`

I wonder is there any other approach?

Thanks

**Update**

Chrome Extension with jQuery sniff elements with classname `editor`, if finds or find them `visible it inserts text, say`Hello World`. If`Hello World`already there, it does not end. So far it's working fine. Issue is what if user manually removed **Hello World**, the code which is running under`setinterval` block adds it again. I don't want this second addition as the code should not add *Hello World* in element where it was already added.

Comment: Unable to understand the question :(

Comment: Can you explain this statement `if it does not find certain text, add it.`?
And then....
`So far it's working.` - What is working? Share some sample in jsfiddle and explain.

Comment: @JohnR Explanation added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user removes text (you mean textarea?) from a div, you can mark it with a custom data attribute.

```
element.data('skip', true);
```

And implement a check in your timer to skip elements with this data attribute.

```
if (!element.data('skip'))
{
    // do your thing
}
```

More info here: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Explanation added. Yeah `Textarea`

Comment: Much neater approach. No need of generating IDs.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like any browser has that feature built in. You can obviously build it yourself using I don't want to copy any answers so I'll leave you with this link:
[Unique identifier for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298500/unique-identifier-for-html-elements)

Comment: Awkward moment when you find IE did something good and other did not.

Comment: Haha, yea, but I guess you call it redundant