# Create a unique identifier for a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an object that stores various elements and their CSS properties.

**The code I have now:**

```
// My object
var cssStorage = {};

function store(element, cssProperty, value) {
    // Initialize the (sub-)objects if they don't exist
    cssStorage[element.id] = cssStorage[element] || {};
    cssStorage[element.id][cssProperty] = cssStorage[element][cssProperty] || {};

    // Set the cssProperty to equal the value
    cssStorage[element.id][cssProperty] = value;
};
```

**Example:**

```
// My element
var box = document.getElementById("box");

// Let's call the function twice to save to properties
store(box, "display", "block");
store(box, "height", "74px");
```

**Now my Object is populated like so:**

```
cssStorage = {
    box: { // <- box is the id of the HTML element <div id = "box"></div>
        // The property-value pairs
        display: "block",
        height: "74px"
    }
};
```

**So now, if I type the code in the console:**

```
return cssStorage.box.display; // Returns "block"
```

---

As you saw in the first block of code I posted, I used **`element.id`** as the element's **`unique identifier`**, to be able to use it as shown right above.

My problem is the dependency of my script upon **`element.id`**. Some elements of my DOM don't have an **`id`** and therefore the function is useless for these elements.

---

In essence, what I want to achieve is to call the function **`store`** **when my element doesn't have an `ID`** as follows:

```
// Some ways to get an element
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")[0];
var box = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var box = document.getElementsByName("jack")[0];

// It'll show an error, as the function uses 'element.id' and my element doesn't have one
store(box, "display", "block");
```

**Is there a unique identifier for every node in the DOM?**

Something that I could use as the name of:

```
cssStorage = {
    [THE NAME]: {}
};
```

**If not, how can I create a unique identifier for my elements, so that I can use the function as shown above without needing an id, class or other property that my element may not have?**

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could generate a guid and assign it as data attribute to that element e.g. `data-guid` (though this wouldn't persist if the page changed) Is persistence required?

Comment: are you on angular ? how about custom directive ?

Comment: @DBS No, not at all. It can set a different one each time provided that two elements don't have the same one.

Comment: @IndraUprade Vanilla JavaScript. No frameworks :)

Comment: Only glanced at the code... `something.[someProp]` is wrong. You need `something[someProp]` if `someProp` is a variable or `something.someProp` if "someProp" is the actual name of the property.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson just a typo.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Added vanila script in answer, please check if it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique identifier for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298500/unique-identifier-for-html-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily coin a unique identifier for any element that doesn't yet have one:

```
var customIDprefix = "__myCustomPrefix__";
var customIDcntr = 0;

function getNextID() {
    return customIDprefix + customIDCntr++;
}
```

And, then you can make sure any element you're using has a unique ID:

```
function checkID(elem) {
    if (!elem.id) {
        elem.id = getNextID();
    }
}
```

---

If you're using ES6, you can also just use a `WeakMap` or `Map` object as your CSSStorage mechanism which let the DOM element itself be the key so you don't have to make a string key.

In that case, you'd just do this:

```
var cssStorage = new Map();

cssStorage[elem] = { // <- elem (your DOM element itself) becomes your key into the cssStorage
    // The property-value pairs
    display: "block",
    height: "74px"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an integer to handle a sequence and set the id to elements that does not have it, prefixing to avoid duplicates (for example '***myid***' + idSequence++).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works. Basically trying to clone the original element and assign it back to the original after adding id with random generator.

```
function store(element, cssProperty, value) {

if ( element.id == undefined ) {
  var clonedElem = element.cloneNode(true);
  clonedElem.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
  element = clonedElem;
}
    // Initialize the (sub-)objects if they don't exist
    cssStorage.[element.id] = cssStorage[element] || {};
    cssStorage.[element.id][cssProperty] = cssStorage.[element][cssProperty] || {};

    // Set the cssProperty to equal the value
    cssStorage.[element.id][cssProperty] = value;
};
```